# How to find the current version of IBM Hyperledger fabric?

Tags: ibm-cloud, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

What is the way to get composer-cli,composer-rest-server, composer-playground version of ibm hyperledger fabric?

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Ubuntu or macOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the installation doc 
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/blockchain/develop_install.html#installing-a-development-environment

For Hyperledger Fabric v1.2.1:

- npm install -g composer-cli@0.20.x
- npm install -g composer-rest-server@0.20.x
- npm install -g generator-hyperledger-composer@0.20.x
- npm install -g composer-playground@0.20.x

Comment: Actually i want to get the current version of enterprise plan of IBM blockchain Service for composer-cli, composer-rest-server, and composer-playground . But inside network preference monitor this info doesn't exist.

Comment: @Aqeel To check the version of npm packages, you can run npm list -g, which gives you the exact version of the packages.

Comment: @Aqeel you can also use the following command to show latest version of a package    ```npm show composer-cli@* version|tail --1 ```

Comment: Thank you very much but i want to know the online environment versions provided by ibm on ibm cloud.

Comment: @Aqeel  you can use the API to get network profile of the IBM cloud blockchain. You would need key, secret and networkid to make the call using CURL. ```curl -X GET -H "accept:application/json" -u {key}:{secret} "https://ibp-sp.us-south.ibm-blockchain-5-prod.cloud.ibm.com/api/v1/networks/{NETWORK_ID}/connection_profile" ``` . You can also Swagger UI from the blockchain console.                             
   GET /networks/{networkID}/connection_profile 
  https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/blockchain/howto/swagger_apis.html#interacting-with-the-network-using-swagger-apis